# CoreData and Entity Relationship Issue

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity, nsset

In my core data model I have two entities:

1. InventoryItem
2. InventoryAction

InventoryItem has the following attributes:
**Attributes:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * allowsActions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * assetID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * inventoryObjectID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * objectDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * retired;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * serialNumber;
```

**Relationships:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *action;
```

InventoryAction has the following attributes
**Attributes:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * actionDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * actionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * actionLongValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * actionShortValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * userActionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userAuthorizingAction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userPerformingAction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * userPerformingActionExt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * inventoryObjectID;
```

**Relationships**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) InventoryItem *object;
```

Now that you have all that information I will tell you that all of the values that are being stored in the CoreData model are coming from a web service in JSON format. All of the values are storing properly.

The problem that I'm having is that when I fetch the data from CoreData it only brings back values that are unique.

For instance:
The last InventoryItem has 6 actions associated with it:

1. "",
2. "",
3. "it looks kinda slimy",
4. "oh god....why would you do that to an inanimate object you sicko",
5. "its all slimy now",
6. "everything looks good"

As 1 and 2 have the same value it only retrieves value 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

Here is the code I'm using to fetch the data:

```
- (void)loadDetails
{
    _fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    _entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InventoryObject" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    _sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"inventoryObjectID" ascending:YES];
    _sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:_sort, nil];

    [_fetchRequest setEntity:_entity];
    [_fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:_sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error;
    _fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (InventoryItem *inventoryItem in _fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Object Description: %@", [inventoryItem valueForKey:@"objectDescription"]);
        NSLog(@"Object ID: %@", [inventoryItem valueForKey:@"inventoryObjectID"]);
        InventoryAction *action = (InventoryAction *)inventoryItem.action;
        NSLog(@"Action Long Value: %@", [action valueForKey:@"actionLongValue"]);
        NSLog(@"Notes: %@", [action valueForKey:@"notes"]);

    }
}
```

Here is the JSON return:

```
[{"MediaInventoryObjectsId":1,"AssetId":15,"Quantity":1,"SerialNumber":"R45DFL5","Description":"Test Camera 1","AllowActions":true,"Retired":false,"Actions":[{"MediaInventoryActionsId":3,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":1,"UserPerformingActionExt":4444,"UserActionId":1,"ActionDate":"2014-05-19T15:31:45.6","UserPerformingAction":"myersb","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":null,"ActionShortValue":"OUT","ActionLongValue":"Check Out"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":4,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":1,"UserPerformingActionExt":4444,"UserActionId":2,"ActionDate":"2014-05-19T15:31:45.6","UserPerformingAction":"myersb","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":"everything looks good","ActionShortValue":"IN","ActionLongValue":"Check In"}]},{"MediaInventoryObjectsId":2,"AssetId":15,"Quantity":2,"SerialNumber":"IDKMYBFFJILL","Description":"Vanilla Ice Cream","AllowActions":true,"Retired":false,"Actions":[]},{"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"AssetId":15,"Quantity":1,"SerialNumber":"R2D23P0","Description":"Droid Bee Box","AllowActions":true,"Retired":false,"Actions":[{"MediaInventoryActionsId":5,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":4444,"UserActionId":1,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.53","UserPerformingAction":"myersb","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":null,"ActionShortValue":"OUT","ActionLongValue":"Check Out"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":6,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":4444,"UserActionId":2,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.58","UserPerformingAction":"myersb","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":"everything looks good","ActionShortValue":"IN","ActionLongValue":"Check In"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":7,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":5555,"UserActionId":1,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.6","UserPerformingAction":"farmer","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":null,"ActionShortValue":"OUT","ActionLongValue":"Check Out"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":8,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":5555,"UserActionId":2,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.6","UserPerformingAction":"farmer","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":"its all slimy now","ActionShortValue":"IN","ActionLongValue":"Check In"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":9,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":6666,"UserActionId":1,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.61","UserPerformingAction":"intern1","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":"it looks kinda slimy","ActionShortValue":"OUT","ActionLongValue":"Check Out"},{"MediaInventoryActionsId":10,"MediaInventoryObjectsId":3,"UserPerformingActionExt":6666,"UserActionId":2,"ActionDate":"2014-05-20T14:48:29.62","UserPerformingAction":"intern1","UserAuthorizingAction":"mccroskeyl","Notes":"oh god....why would you do that to an inanimate object you sicko","ActionShortValue":"IN","ActionLongValue":"Check In"}]}]
```

I read somewhere that NSSet possibly only brings back unique records. Is this true and if so what would be the solution as the relationship: action is an NSSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *action;
```

But you access it like this:

```
InventoryAction *action = (InventoryAction *)inventoryItem.action;
```

That's incorrect. The `action` relationship is an `NSSet` containing instances of `InventoryAction`, it's not an `InventoryAction` itself. Even though you assign this to an `InventoryAction *`, what you actually have is an `NSSet`. Then you do this:

```
NSLog(@"Notes: %@", [action valueForKey:@"notes"]);
```

If you call `valueForKey:` on an `NSSet`, it returns all unique values of that key for objects in the set. In this case it returns all unique values of the `notes` attribute on the `InventoryAction` objects in the set, which is what you're seeing. If you want to find every instance instead of every unique value, you need something like:

```
NSSet *actions = inventoryItem.action;
for (InventoryAction *action in actions) {
    NSLog(@"Action note: %@", action.note);
}
```

[Warning, the above is just typed into my web browser....]